# How to get ReporteRs to work after installing officer

Tags: r, reporters, officer

I've been using the ReporteRs package to generate MS Word documents from R. Due to some Java problems, I tried the officer package as well. Ever since I installed officer, I am unable to load the ReporteRs package:

```
library(ReporteRs)
```

> Loading required package: ReporteRsjars
>
> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : there is no package called ‘officer’
>
> Warning: Error in : package or namespace load failed for ‘ReporteRs’

I've tried deleting all three packages (both using pacman::p_delete() and by physically deleting the folders from my library) and reinstalling.

If I install all three packages, the error message is:

> Error : object ‘ph_from_xml_at’ is not exported by 'namespace:officer'
>   Warning: Error in : package or namespace load failed for ‘ReporteRs’

I can't even find where this function is called from in ReporteRs or ReporteRsjars and I'm completely at loss as to how to go back to what worked.

---

Edit: 
I've tried both using my (usual) microsoft R version, on which ReporteRs has worked before, and regular R 3.4.

sessionInfo():

> R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
>
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0

In the Microsoft client, the sessionInfo is

> R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> locale:
>
> [1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252
>
> attached base packages:

[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

> other attached packages:
>
> [1] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0 RevoUtils_10.0.3     RevoMods_11.0.0      MicrosoftML_1.3.0    mrsdeploy_1.1.0      RevoScaleR_9.1.0
>   [7] lattice_0.20-34      rpart_4.1-10
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>
> [1] codetools_0.2-15       CompatibilityAPI_1.1.0 foreach_1.4.3           grid_3.3.3             R6_2.2.2
>   [6] jsonlite_1.3           curl_2.3               iterators_1.0.8        tools_3.3.3            mrupdate_1.0.1

Comment: output of session info wld be useful. I'm running both of these pkgs on my macOS system w/o issue.

Comment: Not sure it will solve your issue but try this: 0. make sure no R session is opened. 1. delete all libraries (officer, rvg, ReporteRs, ReporteRsjars) manually 2. open a new R session and run `install.packages(c("officer", "ReporteRs"))`.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the reply.  I tried this already, also tried deleting and then installing from cran, your github or from an older Microsoft mran snapshot. Same result every time, except from GitHub it won't even install because it's from source and it fails the 'can the package be loaded test.

Comment: Officer is not listed as a dependency of ReporteRs on cran. Should it be loading functions from officer at all? I can't even find any mention of ph_from_xml_at in the ReporteRs source code.

Comment: Hi BjaRule, I have faced with a similar problem, could you find a solution?

Comment: No @rnorouzian, we gave up. We had to use a non-R product to solve the issues. I would have strongly preferred an R based solution.

Comment: If you're just interested in exporting graphs to Word & Powerpoint you can also use my new package export that's built on top of officer: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export